# Changing from Client Profile to Full removes add service reference

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-client-profile

The title says pretty much everything.

When I try to add a reference to a DLL it disappears, this is due to targeting the Client Profile instead of the full profile. I've Googled and found the fix for this is to change the target to Full Profile. 
However, when I change to Full Profile the Service References "folder" turns in to a normal folder and the compiler moans that SERV_REF is not found (presumbly because of the fact that the service reference folder is no longer acting like a reference)
Why is the client profile allowing me the add service reference and working but the full profile is not?

Many Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Do you have the same problem in the latest Visual Studio?  If you think you've found a bug, it should be reported on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Also, does it work right if you remove the reference, change the profile, and then add the reference again?

Comment: No, when I change to the full framework I don't even have the option to add service reference. 
I don't have a newer Visual Studio to test it on.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I've just tested on the 2013 RC and found that it says "The current project desn't support service references...Enable WCF support change target version"
I was under the understanding that it was client profile that lacked WCF/Service References and full was, well, full